# ua - ubuntu-advantage unit installed but not subscribed

Tags: ubuntu-advantage

I am not a Ubuntu Advantage subscriber but there's this systemd unit active and waiting on my 21.04

```
 ua-messaging.timer    loaded active waiting   Ubuntu Advantage update messaging
```

Ubuntu Advantage I understand is a program for enterprise support.

I some part of UA important for a civilian user's installation or is this installed as a convenience for optional UA enrollment? If the latter, I assume it can be removed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply remove it by

```
sudo apt-get autopurge ubuntu-advantage-tools
```

---

I have just checked my supported and not-EOL Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.
It has `ua-messaging.timer` from `ubuntu-advantage-tools` package installed too.
So I have reported [bug 1928604](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-advantage-tools/+bug/1928604) to launchpad.